# What does the speed of light have to do with mass and energy?

Tags: mass-energy

I've been thinking about Einstein recently, and I came back to the famous equation e=mc^2.  Why does this work?  It's saying the difference between mass and energy happens to be the speed of light squared?  I'm sure there's a larger explanation behind it, but the simplicity of the equation seems improbable.

Comment: Obligatory reminder that the full form of the equation is $E = \sqrt{p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4}$.